# CSS multi-image background rows?

Tags: css

I did a through search and could not find an answer to my particular query...Granted that may be due to my novice ability and flawed thinking.  What I am trying to accomplish is a two rows of 3 non-tiled, non-repeating, side-by-side images...set as my webpage background.

Here is the basic HTML formatting that I'd like to duplicate as a CSS Background:

```
<HTML>
<span><img src="images/image1.gif"><img src="images/image2.gif"><img src="images/image3.gif"><BR><img src="images/image4.gif"><img src="images/image5.gif"><img src="images/image6.gif"></span>
<HTML>
```

Here is my crude attempt at a CSS solution:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
body
{ background-image: url('images/image1.gif'), url('images/image2.gif'), url('images/image3.gif'), url('images/image4.gif'), url('images/image5.gif'), url('images/image6.gif'); background-repeat: no-repeat; }
</style>
```

Although this did "work" ...all I managed to do was stack 6 images directly on top of each other in the top left corner.  Any help for a newb would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you know each image's dimension, you can use `background-position`;

Comment: You can use your HTML, but give that <span> `position:absolute` and `z-index:-1` to make it act as a background.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign `background-position` to each of the background-image explicitly. This should work for your condition:

```
background-position: top left, top center, top right, bottom left, bottom center, bottom right;
```

Also have a look at [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size) css property.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3DuBd/)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that and it does set the images up side-by-side...but due to the images size(350 px) there are huge gaps in between each one.  I would like to have them in a clean row with no gaps.  Is there a way to accomplish this with CSS?

Comment: @user2138961 As I mentioned, have a look at `background-size` property (Check my updated post with a link). or else do calculations to make it fit. :).